# html table layout is not fixed in outlook,for a email template

Tags: html

Following is my code to keep table layout fixed,but it`s layout not fixed when I get a mail in outlook->

```
<table border=1 borderColor='solid #9BBB59 2.25pt' style='border-top: solid #9BBB59 2.25pt;border-bottom: solid #9BBB59 2.25pt;border-left: solid #9BBB59 2.25pt;border-right: solid #9BBB59 2.25pt;table-layout:fixed;width=82%'>
```

I have two table,I`m trying to maintain same width for both the tables,it`s working in IE when I paste html code in a file,but it`s not working in outlook,width varies...
Is there a way I can Fix this??

Answer (score 0):

For your situation I consider wrapping the two tables inside a same table container to have same widths in outlook.

Comment: It worked,there was a mistake like ''width=82%'' this is wrong,in style it should be like 'width:82%'.

Comment: Oh I had some problem creating with Outlook 2010 in rendering CSS attributes. Outlook 2010 used MS word rendering engine which is a humbug..

[link]http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2799/microsoft-to-ignore-web-standards-in-outlook-2010/

Comment: @Ravi You should consider that there are other Outlook email clients since 2010.  But in general we use lots of CSS with Outlook, you just have to be careful

Comment: This might help you to understand which bits are usable and which are not https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem recently and I resolved it using a combination of few things.

Most importantly, ensure you have a table width which is slightly more than the sum of your individual column widths. And use this style in your "" or "" elements : style="word-break:break-all"

```
<HTML style="font-family:arial;font-size:15px;">
    <style>
           table, th, td { border:thin solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left; font-size:15px; font-weight: normal;}
    </style>
    <table width="600" cellpadding="5">
        <tr style="background-color:#045411; color:white;font-family:arial;font-size:15px;">
            <th width="100">ID</th>
            <th width="200" style="word-break:break-all">Name</th>
            <th width="200" style="word-break:break-all">Description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:black;background-color:white;font-family:arial;font-size:15px;">
            <td width="100">I3026</td>
            <td width="200" style="word-break:break-all">ABFCL3hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</td>
            <td width="200" style="word-break:break-all">lalalalalalallallalalalalalallallalalalalalallallalalalalalallallalalalalalallallalalalalalallallalalalalalallallalalalalalallallalalalalalallallalalalalalallallalalalalalallal</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table width="600" cellpadding="5">
        <tr style="background-color:#045411; color:white;">
            <th width="100">ID</th>
            <th width="200" style="word-break:break-all">Name</th>
            <th width="200" style="word-break:break-all">Description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:black;background-color:white;">
            <td width="100">ABC100</td>
            <td width="200" style="word-break:break-all"></td>
            <td width="200" style="word-break:break-word">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</HTML>
```